# Pegar todos os campos de uma classe usando Lambda + Group By

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma lista:

```
produtosCompletos = (from f in estoques
                     join p in produtos on f.idProduto equals p.id
                     join c in classes on f.idClasse equals c.id
                     select new produtoCompleto()
                     {
                         idUnidade = f.idUnidade,
                         descricao = p.descricao,
                         classe = c.descricao,
                         lote = f.lote,
                         dtValidade = f.dtValidade,
                         quant = f.quant
                     }).ToList();
```

Com essa lista, eu quero somar o valor quant agrupado pela descricao. Estou fazendo assim:

```
        var result =
            (from p in produtosCompletos
            group p by p.descricao
            into g
            select new produtoCompleto()
            {
                idUnidade = //não sei como mostrar aqui :/
                descricao = g.Key,
                quant = g.Sum(x => x.quant)
            }).ToList();
```

Como podem ver acima, só consigo pegar a `descricao` e a `quant`, os outros campos eu não sei como pegar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa pegar o primeiro item do grupo e pegar o id.

```
var result =
            (from p in produtosCompletos
             group p by p.descricao
            into g
             select new produtoCompleto()
             {
                 idUnidade = g.First().idUnidade,
                 descricao = g.Key,
                 quant = g.Sum(x => x.quant)
             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Para fazer um `group by` com diversos campos no linq, você precisa declarar todos os campos desejados na sua clausula, do `group by`, ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```
 var result =
            (from p in produtosCompletos
            group p by new {p.descricao, p.idUnidade }
            into g
            select new produtoCompleto()
            {
                idUnidade = g.Key.idUnidade 
                descricao = g.Key.descricao,
                quant = g.Sum(x => x.quant)
            }).ToList();
```

Você pode acessar suas variáveis depois através da `Key`